# Quadratic equation involving floor function.

Tags: quadratics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If equations $x^2-3x+4=0$ and $ 4x^2-2\lfloor3a+b\rfloor x+b=0\space (a,b\space\epsilon\space R) $ have a common root then the complete set of values of $a$ is ?

I have not yet been able to develop an approach to this problem. How do I go about it?

**Edit :**

I was able to solve and obtain the common root as $ x= \frac{b-16}{2\lfloor3a+b\rfloor -12} $.

After this, how do I obtain the range of $a$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin first by noting that the roots of $x^2-3x+4$ are complex conjugates, $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, and that the coefficients in $4x^2-2\lfloor 3a+b\rfloor x + b$ are real.  If $\alpha_i$ is a nonreal root of a quadratic with real coefficients, its complex conjugate is also a root.

From this, it follows that $g(x)=4x^2-2\lfloor 3a+b\rfloor x + b$ is some multiple of $f(x)=x^2-3x+4$.  Looking at the $x^2$ term, we find then that $4f(x)=g(x)$.  Equating the coefficients together, we have then $b=4\cdot 4 = 16$ and $-2\lfloor 3a+b\rfloor = -3\cdot 4$ from which it follows after some arithmetic that $\lfloor 3a\rfloor = -10$.

Thus, the possible pairs of points $(a,b)$ are $\{(a,b)~:~\frac{-10}{3}\leq a < -3, b=16\}$

Comment: Then how do I obtain the range of a?

Comment: @Arpan Now that you have solved for $\alpha$ as in your edit above, remember that $\alpha$ is specifically a root of each of the original functions.  As in Autolatry's answer above, $\alpha = \frac{3\pm\sqrt{-7}}{2}$.  The roots we see are complex, and the floor function is only defined for real numbers.  We will know then that the imaginary part of 3a is the additive inverse of the imaginary part of b for the floor to make any sense.  Try to simplify what you can to get $a$ as isolated as possible in terms of the root(s) and $b$.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said. a and b are real, so their imaginary parts are zero?

Comment: Oh of course! If imaginary roots occur in a polynomial with real coefficients, they must occur in conjugate pairs. Therefore, both the equations must be identical, right?

Comment: That is true, yes.  You might try running with that idea that the equations should be multiples of one another then to show that $4\cdot f(x)= g(x)$, showing $b=16$ and $-12=-2\lfloor 3a+b\rfloor \Rightarrow 6 = \lfloor 3a+16\rfloor \Rightarrow -10=\lfloor 3a\rfloor$

Comment: That did yield the answer, thank you!

Comment: That also answers the question of why the earlier work seemed to suggest the empty set!  We accidentally did zero divided by zero there apparently.  (we forgot to check the case that the bottom was zero separately)

Comment: That "Oohhh!" moment :P

Answer (score 0):

The roots to the first quadratic are $x_{\pm}=\frac{3}{2}\pm \frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2}$; in terms of the second quadratic; my advice would be to solve
$$
4x^{2}-2(3a+b)x+b=0
$$
ignroing the floor; once you have a relationship between the roots to the first and the secodn implement the propertiers of the floor to come up with possible values of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

I would rearrange the first equation to mak $x^2=3x-4$ and substitute that into the second equation as a starting point. Everything is linear  after that.